# When using subfiles package, where it the proper location to add the bibliography files?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, ubuntu

I am trying to add my bib files for my PhD dissertation and I am getting an error message that says I have an empty bibliography and citations are missing.  I used the subfiles package to break up individual chapters and subchapters which is awesome!  However, I would like to get the bibliography working so that my citations show up.

The current file structure for my project is as follows:

```
dissertation/
|-- Dissertation.tex
|-- Dissertation.cls
|-- makefile (Dissertation, release, clean)
|-- Release/
|   |-- Dissertation.pdf
|-- Chapter1/
|   |-- Intro1.tex
|   |-- Methods1.tex
|   |-- Results1.tex
|   |-- Discussion1.tex
|   |-- Conclusion1.tex
|   |-- Figures/
|       | -- Figure1.pdf
|       | -- Figure2.pdf
|       | -- Figure3.pdf
|   |-- bib_files/ 
|       | -- bib1.bib
|   |-- makefile (Chapter1, Intro1, Methods1, release, clean, etc.)
|   |-- Release/
|   |-- | -- Chapter1.pdf
|   |-- | -- Intro1.pdf
|   |-- | -- Methods1.pdf
|-- Chapter2/
|   |-- Intro2.tex
|   |-- Methods2.tex
|   |-- Results2.tex
|   |-- Discussion2.tex
|   |-- Conclusion2.tex
|   |-- bib_files/ 
|       | -- bib2.bib
|   |-- Figures/
|       | -- Figure1.pdf
|       | -- Figure2.pdf
|       | -- Figure3.pdf
|   |-- makefile (Chapter2, Intro2, Methods2, release, clean, etc.)
|   |-- Release/
|   |-- | -- Chapter2.pdf
|   |-- | -- Intro2.pdf
|   |-- | -- Methods2.pdf
|-- AppendixA/
|   |-- AppendixA.tex
|   |-- Code/
|       | -- code1.py
|       | -- code2.m
|       | -- code3.cc
|   |-- Data/
|       | -- Data1.csv
|       | -- Data2.csv
|       | -- Data3.csv
```

I have tried putting the following in my main.tex file:

```
% References
\addbibresource{./Chapter2/bib_files/bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource{./Chapter3/bib_files/bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource{./Chapter4/bib_files/bibliography.bib}
```

I have also tried putting these commands in the individual chapters and that didn't work either:

```
%%% -*-LaTeX-*-
\documentclass[../Dissertation]{subfiles}

\graphicspath{{Chapter2/Figures/}} % Graphics path for images
\addbibresource{./Chapter2/bib_files/bibliography.bib} % Chapter 2 references

\begin{document}
    
    % Needs to be capitalized (University Rules)
    \chapter{\uppercase{Chapter title here}}
    
    \hspace{\parindent}
    Experimental data measurement.
    
    \subfile{./Chapter2/0_Abstract}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/1_Introduction}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/2_Methods}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/3_Results}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/4_Discussion}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/5_Conclusion}
    \subfile{./Chapter2/6_Acknowledgment}
    
    % bibliography
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=references]
    
\end{document}
```

However, each of these approaches was unsuccessful.

In my .cls file here is how I have defined the bibliography:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                               References
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\RequirePackage[defernums=true,
                hyperref,
                backref,
                backend=biber,
                style=ieee,
                natbib=true,
                refsegment=chapter,
                block=space
                ]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend, biber

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} % Spacing between items in bilbiography

% Define typesetting of references heading
\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
    \section{#1}% Add section so that the table of contents adds the chapter references
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
    \singlespacing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------%
%                           Final Bibliography
%   Add type=book, article, online, thesis for specific references
%----------------------------------------------------------------------%

\def\finalBibliography{
    {\singlespacing
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={\uppercase{Bibliography}}] % Whole
    }
}
```

At the very end of my main.tex I call my `\finalBibliography` to show all citations used.

I am also using Ubuntu to execute, compile, and output the final PDF here after a lot of help from previous posts with my final command being `make file`:

```
DISSERTATION = Dissertation
TEX = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape 
BIBTOOLS = biber
OPEN = open -a Skim.app
RESOURCES = ${DISSERTATION}.pdf

# Executables
default:
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${OPEN} ${DISSERTATION}

# Order of compiling (LaTeX --> biber -->  LaTeX --> LaTeX)
file:
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}
    ${TEX} ${DISSERTATION}

clean:  
    rm -rf auto *_minted-* *.log *.aux *.synctex.gz *.out *.toc *.run *.bcf *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.run.xml *.pdf
    
release:
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp *.pdf Release
    make clean
```

Here is the makefile for each individual chapter/section (Chapter2 specific):

```
CHAPTER = Chapter2
ABSTRACT = 0_Abstract
INTRODUCTION = 1_Introduction
METHODS = 2_Methods
RESULTS = 3_Results
DISCUSSION = 4_Discussion
CONCLUSION = 5_Conclusion
ACKNOWLEDGE = 6_Acknowledgment

# Tex commands
TEX = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape 
BIBTOOLS = biber
OPEN = open -a Skim.app
RESOURCES = ${CHAPTER}.pdf

# Executables
default:
    ${TEX} ${CHAPTER}
    ${OPEN} ${CHAPTER}

clean:
    rm -rf auto *_minted-* *.log *.aux *.synctex.gz* *.out *.bcf *.run *run.xml *.pdf *.swo *.swp

release:
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp *.pdf Release
    make clean

chapter:
    ${TEX} ${CHAPTER}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${CHAPTER}
    ${TEX} ${CHAPTER}
    ${TEX} ${CHAPTER}
    
file:   
    make chapter
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp ${RESOURCES} Release
    make clean

abstract:
    ${TEX} ${ABSTRACT}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${ABSTRACT}
    ${TEX} ${ABSTRACT}
    ${TEX} ${ABSTRACT}

introduction:
    ${TEX} ${INTRODUCTION}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${INTRODUCTION}
    ${TEX} ${INTRODUCTION}
    ${TEX} ${INTRODUCTION}
    
methods:
    ${TEX} ${METHODS}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${METHODS}
    ${TEX} ${METHODS}
    ${TEX} ${METHODS}

results:
    ${TEX} ${RESULTS}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${RESULTS}
    ${TEX} ${RESULTS}
    ${TEX} ${RESULTS}

discussion:
    ${TEX} ${DISCUSSION}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${DISCUSSION}
    ${TEX} ${DISCUSSION}
    ${TEX} ${DISCUSSION}
    
conclusion:
    ${TEX} ${CONCLUSION}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${CONCLUSION}
    ${TEX} ${CONCLUSION}
    ${TEX} ${CONCLUSION}

acknowledge:
    ${TEX} ${ACKNOWLEDGE}
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${ACKNOWLEDGE}
    ${TEX} ${ACKNOWLEDGE}
    ${TEX} ${ACKNOWLEDGE}
```

If you have any suggestions, that would be fantastic.  The commands don't seem to execute the creation of the bibliography.

Here is a sample error output:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kita_1992' on page 24 undefined on input line 146.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Kita_1990' on page 24 undefined on input line 152.

[24]) (./5_Conclusion.tex [25]) (./6_Acknowledgment.tex)

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 25.

[26] (./Chapter2.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                Chapter2
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
```

After trying to only run the biber command to create the bibliography

```
BIBTOOLS = biber
bib:
    ${BIBTOOLS} ${DISSERTATION}
```

I am getting this error message and I'm not sure how to debug it:

```
biber Dissertation
INFO - This is Biber 2.14 (beta)
INFO - Logfile is 'Dissertation.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'Dissertation.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
make: *** [Makefile:20: bib] Error 2
```

Comment: Leave the `\addbibresource` commands in the main preamble, but add `\subfix` around the path name, i.e., `\addbibresource{\subfix{./Chapter2/bib_files/bibliography.bib}}`. The preambles of the subfiles will only be processed when typesetting the subfile separately.

Comment: I added the `\subfix{...}` inside of the `\addbibresource` and it still resulted in the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact location of your `.bib` files does not matter. Most sensible things that work in a 'normal' (non-`subfiles`) setup also work with `subfiles`, but you need to factor in the effect changes in working/compile directory have on relative paths.

You haven't shared a whole lot about your folder setup, so I will assume something that looks roughly like this

```
dissertation/
|-- main.tex
|-- chapter1/
|   |-- chap1.tex
|   \-- bib1.bib
|-- chapter2/
|   |-- chap2.tex
|   \-- bib2.bib
```

and that you compile your `main` file from `dissertation` as working directory and the chapters from their own directories (so `cd chapter1`, `pdflatex chapter1`, `biber chapter1`, `pdflatex chapter1`, `pdflatex chapter1`).

Then your `main.tex` should look roughly like this

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, refsegment=chapter,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\subfix{chapter1/bib1.bib}}
\addbibresource{\subfix{chapter2/bib2.bib}}

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1/chap1}
\subfile{chapter2/chap2}

\printbibliography[title={Complete \refname}]
\end{document}
```

and your subfiles like this

```
% chap1.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

and

```
% chap2.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Dolor}
Dolor \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

The problem we have to work around is that file names are always resolved relative to where you invoke LaTeX/Biber. So when you compile `main.tex` in `dissertation` all file names are resolved relative to that directory, so the `\addbibresource` calls need to include the subdirectory names `chapter1/` and `chapter2/`. But when you compile `chap1.tex` from `chapter1`, the relative path of the `.bib` file is not `chapter1/bib1.bib`, it is just `bib1.bib`. That's what `\subfix` does for us: It fixes the file path issue when the subfile is compiled on its own.

---

An alternative, but less elegant method would be to explicitly branch on whether or not we are typesetting the main or the subfile.

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, refsegment=chapter,]{biblatex}

\ifSubfilesClassLoaded
  { }
  {
    \addbibresource{chapter1/bib1.bib}%
    \addbibresource{chapter2/bib2.bib}%
  }

\begin{document}
\subfile{chapter1/chap1}
\subfile{chapter2/chap2}

\printbibliography[title={Complete \refname}]
\end{document}
```

`chapter1/chap1.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\addbibresource{bib1.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I posted the file structure that I currently have as well as the two make files for the main (dissertation) and individual chapters.  I think the only difference from the format that you posted is my bibliography bib files are in a separate folder titled "bib_files". Would I use the same format that you mentioned just adding the additional folder path?

Comment: @ChristopherCreveling As I say at the very beginning of the answer: The exact file path is irrelevant as long as the general approach is correct: Use `\subfix` to fix the relative file path. It works with `\addbibresource{\subfix{chapter1/bib1.bib}}` as in my example and should work the same with `\addbibresource{\subfix{Chapter2/bib_files/bibliography.bib}}`. Why don't you experiment a bit with `\subfix` and your file paths?

Comment: That makes sense.  I have updated my .tex files to reflect that change.  I experimented with just trying to run the command `biber Dissertation` and that didn't seem to work which might be why I haven't been able to reference the .bib files mentioned above.  I will add it to the end of the question.

Comment: @ChristopherCreveling As explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and alluded to in my answer to your other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584971/35864) you need to run a full compile cycle of LaTeX (i.e. pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX), Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. Running just Biber on an empty directory is not going to be enough.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help.  After running each command separately I am able to get this to work with the citations in the proper order and referenced!, e.g. `make file` ---> `make bib` ---> `make file` ---> `make file`.  I guess I'm not sure why my `Makefile` doesn't execute the order.  It seems to stop after the first step.  Maybe that should be my entire question instead?

Comment: @moewe In `chap1.tex`, it is not necessary to use `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` in the preamble, as the preamble is only executed when the file is typeset as the main file (i.e., when `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` is true), and is skipped when loading the file with `\subfile`.

Comment: @gernot Thank you very much for the hint. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone's comments!  Long story short everyone was right.  However, what wasn't working was the `Makefile` to execute the commands.

Here was the previous `Makefile`:

```
# variables
FILE = Dissertation
TEX = pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape 
BIBTOOL = biber

tex:
    ${TEX} ${FILE}
bib:
    ${BIBTOOL} ${FILE}
```

I noticed that when I split up each command i.e. `make tex` followed by `make bib` then `make tex` and make `tex` it did work, but that was long and extensive to run.

After being pointed in the right direction the program ***latexmk*** is used to deal with compiling multiple times to ensure that the citations/figures/references, etc. are in the correct order.  With that change to my `Makefile`, everything seems to be in good working order.

Here is the updated `Makefile`

```
# Linux Makefile to create a final pdf of the project

# Variables
FILE = PhD_Presentation

# PDF LaTeX specific
PDFLATEX = "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 --shell-escape"

# You want latexmk to *always* run, because make does not have all the info.
# Also, include non-file targets in .PHONY so they are run regardless of any
# file of the given name existing.
.PHONY: ${FILE}.pdf all clean

# The first rule in a Makefile is the one executed by default ("make"). It
# should always be the "all" rule, so that "make" and "make all" are identical.
all: ${FILE}.pdf

# CUSTOM BUILD RULES

# In case you didn't know, '$@' is a variable holding the name of the target,
# and '$<' is a variable holding the (first) dependency of a rule.
# "raw2tex" and "dat2tex" are just placeholders for whatever custom steps
# you might have.

%.tex: %.raw
    ./raw2tex $< > $@

%.tex: %.dat
    ./dat2tex $< > $@

# MAIN LATEXMK RULE

# -pdf tells latexmk to generate PDF directly (instead of DVI).
# -pdflatex="" tells latexmk to call a specific backend with specific options.
# -use-make tells latexmk to call make for generating missing files.

# -interaction=nonstopmode keeps the pdflatex backend from stopping at a
# missing file reference and interactively asking you for an alternative.

# --shell-escape allows for *minted to run code highlighting

# -f forces latexmk to run until compiling has been complete regardless of
#  cross referencing (i.e. it continues to run until references are in the
#  correct location)

${FILE}.pdf: ${FILE}.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=${PDFLATEX} -f -use-make ${FILE}.tex

# Clean up unnecessary files
clean:
    latexmk -C
    # specific to latexmk

clear:  
    rm -rf auto *_minted-* *.log *.aux *.synctex.gz *.out *.toc *.run *.bcf *.lof *.lot *.tdo *.run.xml *.pdf *.bbl *.blg *.nav *.snm

release:
    rm -rf Release
    mkdir Release
    cp *.pdf Release
    make clear
    make clean
```